# Logarithm (Defined x)

Tags: logarithms

This question is hard for me.
Solve the equation:

$ \log(5(4x-7))=\log(5(x-2))+1$

Can anybody help me with this question, please?

Thanks.

Comment: I can help you! How far did you get with this? Perhaps the first idea would be to try to get rid of the logarithms, right? Maybe you could try to transform the right-hand side to be something like $\log_5 (\ldots)$. In other words, so that the "+1" is inside the logarithms.

Comment: is it log base 5?

Comment: Yes it was log base 5

Comment: I am going to submit the answer for log_5.

Comment: If you still need it

Comment: I guess Darius is asking:  Is it really perhaps $\log_5(4x-7)=\log_5(x-2)+1$

Comment: Yes, exactly . .

Comment: Actually thats the answer that i nedd

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciates it

Answer (score 1):

The idea to apply $\exp(x)$  to both side and you get

$$e^{\log(5(4x-7))}=e^{(\log(5(x-2))+1)}$$

$$20x-35=e^{\log(5(x-2))}.e^{1}$$

$$\frac{20x-35}{e}=5x-10 $$

$$\text{So }\, x=\dfrac{35+10e}{20-5e}.$$

Answer (score 0):

IF the equation is the following:

$\log_5(4x−7)=\log_5(x−2)+1$

$5^{\log_5(4x−7)}=5^{\log_5(x−2)+1} $

$5^{\log_5(4x−7)}=5^{\log_5(x−2)} \cdot 5 $

$4x-7 = 5 (x-2) $

$4x-7 = 5x - 10 $

$- x = -3 $

$x=3$

Comment: Can i ask you something

Comment: What happen if i replace 1 with 3

Comment: Replacing 1 by 3 would obtain:

Comment: $\log_5(4x-7) = \log_5(x-2)+3 \Rightarrow 5^{\log_5(4x-7)} = 5^{\log_5(x-2)+3} 
 \Rightarrow 5^{\log_5(4x-7)} = 5^{\log_5(x-2)} \cdot  5^3 \Rightarrow 4x-7 = 5^3(x-2)$. In general, replacing 1 with n, thus we would obtain  $\log_5(4x-7) = \log_5(x-2)+n \Rightarrow 4x-7 = 5^n(x-2) $

Comment: Ok Thanks Darius